# Drupal hook is not applied to the website

Tags: php, drupal, hook, drupal-webform

I am writing a custom hook in my request related webform which grants access of a radios field (approve, reject, forward to) to the email address that is entered in an email field (by requestor).

the whole idea is:

**requetor submits a form** -> **director will receive an email with the link and choose whether he wants to approve, reject, or pass it to the executives by editing form**

I chose **webform_alter** hook to achieve this

```
function ach_request_form_alter(array &$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

if($form_id == 'ach_request') { //form's id

if($form['submitted_to']['#value'] === \Drupal::currentUser()->getEmail) { //if the value of the email element is equal to the email address of the current user (director);

$form['approval_state_']['#access'] = TRUE; //the radios element would be visible to the director with the same email address

}

}

}
```

Then I used drush cr in terminal but the select element is still not visible. Is there anything wrong with my code? Or do I need to change anything on UI as well?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you implement hooks, the "hook" part of the function name should be replaced with the module or theme name where it resides.
For example,
if you are trying to implement [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.8.x) and you have placed your function in your custom module named "mycoolmodule", your function name would be...

```
/**
* Implements hook_form_alter in a module called mycoolmodule.
*/
function mycoolmodule_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  // do something with the form here
}
```

[Understanding hooks page on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/understanding-hooks)

Comment: Actually I added my code in  hook_webform_submission_form_alter in webform.api.php because I am using the webform.

Comment: to achieve what I am trying to do, is there any other webform hook you recommend? I used hook_webform_element_alter initially and the change is not applied.

Comment: You don't want to put any code in to the contrib module files, and anyway, webform.api.php is never used anyway, it is just a file to show what function are available, the functions in that file are never called. To implement a hook, you put your function in either a custom module or in your custom theme's .theme file

Comment: There is a [docs page dedicated to webform](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/webform). There is a specific webform hook for settings access `hook_webform_element_access` that may be what you want to use. It is outlined in [webform.api.php here](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform/-/blob/6.1.x/webform.api.php#L229)

Comment: I just learned (right after asking you the question) that webform.api.php does nothing since it's just an example. So I created a new module in custom folder that I created and the change is not applied yet.

Comment: I will look at  `hook_webform_element_access` thank you.

Comment: Would you mine answering my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72490572/time-element-is-printing-the-date-as-well-drupal-9-webform) if you are familiar with Twig?